# How do I evaluate this exponential expression without divide-by-zero problems?

Tags: floating-point, precision

I am trying to avoid divide by zero errors for the following expression,

`(1-exp(-a)) / a`.

When a=0 the expression should return 1.  I could use the `expm1` function to avoid truncation error, but division by zero still causes a problem.

Is there a function like `expm1` but with the division by `a`?

Comment: You have not specified a programming language, but I doubt there is any routine customized for this outside of specialized math software. Is there a reason `a ? -expm1(-a)/a : 1` is not satisfactory? One answer suggests `exp(-a/2) * sinh(a/2) / (a/2)`, but then you are calling two complicated functions instead of one, which is not likely to perform better than the test and branch induced by the ternary expression above. A customized routine could be crafted, but that is complicated work and rarely worth the effort. Do you need exceptional performance? What domain of `a` must be supported?

Comment: `a` can be any real number.  It often has value 0 or nearly zero.  But can be as large as 100.

Answer (score 2):

Use an if else statement for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you can rewrite the expression as,

```
(1-exp(-a)) / a = exp(-a/2) * sinh(a/2) / (a/2)
                ~ exp(-a/2) * (1 + 1/6 * (a/2)**2 + 1/120 * (a/2)**4)
```

If `abs(a)>=1e-4` use the original expression, else use the approximation.